# Call Button Click in another button click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a 2 buttons in VB.NET web application called 'Save' and 'Print'.
I want to call 'PRINT button click method' with in a save button?

Is that possible. If possible how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is bad form to call a button's (or other control's) event handlers directly.  Instead put the code that the handler performs in a separate method and call that method from both places.  Something like this:

```
Private Sub PrintButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintButton.Click
    Print()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    'Save code or whatever
    Print()
End Sub

Private Sub Print()
    'Code that does printing or whatever here.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the click event of `Save` Button insert this code

```
Print_Click(sender, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Function and then call the Function in your button.